# Internet Explorer 9 Not Responding after every pass test in Coded UI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I have written a very simple script in Coded UI by recording. The Test runs successfully but if my test passes and I don't close IE from script, IE becomes not responding.
I am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Not the typical behavior, can you show us some code and give us little bit more information what you are testing?

Comment: I am just performing record. As I am a learner, I just performed a recording. I did not record the code for closing the browser (that means it is still open).

Comment: Did you try other tests? Same behavior?